# Is it possible to use different padding for each dimension in conv nets wit keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I would like to use different paddings for different dimensions. In my case I'm using a 3dconvnet. The reason is that I would like to control how how the receptive field and axis squashing occurs for different dimensions. E.g. I would like to have padding equivalent to ("same","same","same") for a few layers and then perhaps ("same","valid","same") for some other layers.

My guess is to do 

 `#maually calculate the paddings
ZeroPadding3D(...)
Conv3D(padding='valid',...)`